# Remote SSH connection from one server to another HANGS, no fail, no error

Tags: ssh, rsync, scp, remote

Trying to copy files from one server to another because the amount of files is not feasible to do by copying to my home pc and then out to second server.

SSH, rync, and scp all hang from either server, but works fine to log in directly over SSH either from web terminal or from putty over SSH.

- I whitelisted IP of server 1 to CSF on server 2.
- I whitelisted IP of server 2 to CSF on server 1.
- I completely turned off CSF on both servers to see if it was blocked by the firewall.

More details about my systems:

**Server1:**

> *Dedicated Server*
>  CentOS 7 [Latest]
>  CloudLinux OS+ [Latest] *(ImmunifyAV is not installed)*
>  ConfigServer Security & Firewall *(IP from server2 whitelisted)*
> ConfigServer Outgoing Spam Monitor
> ConfigServer eXploit Scanner
>  ConfigServer Mailscanner FE
> Engintron

**Server2:**

> *Dedicated Server*
>  CentOS 7 [Latest]
>  CloudLinux OS [Latest] *(ImmunifyAV is not installed)*
> ConfigServer Security & Firewall *(IP from server1 whitelisted)*
> Engintron

I added this into sshd_config:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
AllowUsers root otheruser
```

I verified the port on both servers using this:

```
# netstat -plant | grep :22
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      101059/sshd
tcp        0      0 <server.2.ip>:22         <myhomeip.via.web.terminal>:61177     ESTABLISHED 102710/sshd: root@p
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      101059/sshd
```

Example output:

every one of these commands outputs those 4 lines of code (starting with `OpenSSH_7.4p1`) and hangs (nothing else happens, it doesn't terminate and no error):

## From server 2:

```
# ssh -A -t -v root@server2.mydomain.com -p 22     
         
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to server2.mydomain.com [<server2.ip>] port 22
```

hangs

```
ssh -A -t -v root@server1.mydomain.com -p 22 scp /testnew /testfolder
```

hangs

```
ssh -A -t -v root@server1.mydomain.com -p 22 /testnew /testfolder
```

hangs

```
ssh -A -t -v root@server1.mydomain.com -p 22 scp /testfolder root@server2.mydomain.com -p 22 /testnew
```

hangs

```
rsync -a -e "ssh -p 22" root@server2.mydomain.com:/testfolder /testnew
```

hangs

## From server 1:

```
ssh -A -t -v server2.mydomain.com -p 22 scp /testnew /testfolder
```

hangs

```
ssh -A -t -v server2.mydomain.com -p 22 /testnew /testfolder
```

hangs

```
ssh -A -t -v server2.mydomain.com -p 22 scp /testfolder root@server1.mydomain.com -p 22 /testnew
```

hangs

```
rsync -r -v --progress -e "ssh -p 22" root@server1.mydomain.com:/testfolder /testnew
```

hangs

I also tried using a private key by generating a key on one server and uploading it to the other server, and then trying to access the other with SSH, but again, just hangs!

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_dsa root@server1.mydomain.com -p 22
```

nothing! no result at all, only hangs.

What am I doing wrong??

I installed cygwin on my PC and I was able to ssh into both servers just fine. I only can't connect from one server to the other and back. I tried using the web terminal, I tried using putty, all just hangs, nothing. I tried resetting my home connection, I tried everything. Nothing. I'm at a loss and I don't know what else to try.

What am I doing wrong? Why can I access just fine from cygwin on my home pc, and I can access both directly over putty using SSH, but I cannot connect from one server to the other?

=================

Update:

## netstat -r

Here is the output for server1 `netstat -r`

```
Destination           Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default               gateway         0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eno3
<network>/27          0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U         0 0          0 eno3
server1.myserver.com  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns2>         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns3>         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns4>         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns5>         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns6>         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns7>         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns8>         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns9>         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns10>        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns11>        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns12>        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns13>        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns14>        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns15>        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns16>        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns17>        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns18>        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns19>        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns20>        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns21>        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns22>        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns23>        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns24>        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns25>        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns26>        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns27>        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns28>        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns29>        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
<reversedns30>        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno3
link-local            0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eno3
```

> `<network>/27` is the subnet of the network.
>
> `<reversednsX>` is the domain that is used for the reverse DNS like
> mydomain5.com.
>
> `server1.myserver.com` in this one, and in the following output, `server2.myserve` which appears to be the first part of it in that terminal, this is simply what shows when no reverse dns is set up to attach a domain to that IP. It doesn't affect the network.
>
> Both networks are working fine. Both can be accessed
> over SSH. They just can't contact each other, which is the
> problem.

output from server2 `netstat -r`

```
Destination         Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default             gateway         0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eno1
</28.subnet.ip>.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U         0 0          0 eno1
<broadcast>         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U         0 0          0 eno1
server2.myserve     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno1
server2.myserve     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno1
server2.myserve     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno1
server2.myserve     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno1
server2.myserve     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno1
server2.myserve     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno1
server2.myserve     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno1
server2.myserve     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno1
server2.myserve     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno1
server2.myserve     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno1
server2.myserve     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno1
server2.myserve     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno1
link-local          0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eno1
```

> NOTES:
>
> The netmask of `255.255.255.240` is correct for my server IP. My sites
> are up.
>
> `<broadcast>` = the broadcast ip, in this case 2 #s below my server IP
>
> I didn't include my actual server output above for security

======================

## ip route

output for server1 `ip route`

```
default via <nn>.1 dev eno3
<nn>.0/27 dev eno3 proto kernel scope link src <nn>.2
<nn>.3 dev eno3 scope link src <nn>.3
<nn>.4 dev eno3 scope link src <nn>.4
<nn>.5 dev eno3 scope link src <nn>.5
<nn>.6 dev eno3 scope link src <nn>.6
<nn>.7 dev eno3 scope link src <nn>.7
<nn>.8 dev eno3 scope link src <nn>.8
<nn>.9 dev eno3 scope link src <nn>.9
<nn>.10 dev eno3 scope link src <nn>.10
<nn>.11 dev eno3 scope link src <nn>.11
<nn>.12 dev eno3 scope link src <nn>.12
<nn>.13 dev eno3 scope link src <nn>.13
<nn>.14 dev eno3 scope link src <nn>.14
<nn>.15 dev eno3 scope link src <nn>.15
<nn>.16 dev eno3 scope link src <nn>.16
<nn>.17 dev eno3 scope link src <nn>.17
<nn>.18 dev eno3 scope link src <nn>.18
<nn>.19 dev eno3 scope link src <nn>.19
<nn>.20 dev eno3 scope link src <nn>.20
<nn>.21 dev eno3 scope link src <nn>.21
<nn>.22 dev eno3 scope link src <nn>.22
<nn>.23 dev eno3 scope link src <nn>.23
<nn>.24 dev eno3 scope link src <nn>.24
<nn>.25 dev eno3 scope link src <nn>.25
<nn>.26 dev eno3 scope link src <nn>.26
<nn>.27 dev eno3 scope link src <nn>.27
<nn>.28 dev eno3 scope link src <nn>.28
<nn>.29 dev eno3 scope link src <nn>.29
<nn>.30 dev eno3 scope link src <nn>.30
<xxx>.<xxx>.0.0/16 dev eno3 scope link metric 1003
```

> `<nn>`.2 is the IP of the server itself. `<nn>` is just short for the
> first 3 parts of the network IP, removed for security.
>  
>  For
> reference about this subnet:
>  `<nn>`.1-30  = usable IPs
> `<nn>`.0          = network
>  `<nn>`.31         = broadcast
> 255.255.255.224 = netmask

output for server2 `ip route`

```
default via <xx>.<xx>.<xxx>.49 dev eno1
<xx>.<xx>.<yyy>.0/20 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src <xx>.<xx>.<xxx>.51
<xx>.<xx>.<xxx>.48/28 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src <xx>.<xx>.<xxx>.50
<xx>.<xx>.<xxx>.51 dev eno1 scope link src <xx>.<xx>.<xxx>.51
<xx>.<xx>.<xxx>.52 dev eno1 scope link src <xx>.<xx>.<xxx>.52
<xx>.<xx>.<xxx>.53 dev eno1 scope link src <xx>.<xx>.<xxx>.53
<xx>.<xx>.<xxx>.54 dev eno1 scope link src <xx>.<xx>.<xxx>.54
<xx>.<xx>.<xxx>.55 dev eno1 scope link src <xx>.<xx>.<xxx>.55
<xx>.<xx>.<xxx>.56 dev eno1 scope link src <xx>.<xx>.<xxx>.56
<xx>.<xx>.<xxx>.57 dev eno1 scope link src <xx>.<xx>.<xxx>.57
<xx>.<xx>.<xxx>.58 dev eno1 scope link src <xx>.<xx>.<xxx>.58
<xx>.<xx>.<xxx>.59 dev eno1 scope link src <xx>.<xx>.<xxx>.59
<xx>.<xx>.<xxx>.60 dev eno1 scope link src <xx>.<xx>.<xxx>.60
<xx>.<xx>.<xxx>.61 dev eno1 scope link src <xx>.<xx>.<xxx>.61
<xx>.<xx>.<xxx>.62 dev eno1 scope link src <xx>.<xx>.<xxx>.62
<zzz>.<zzz>.0.0/16 dev eno1 scope link metric 1002
```

> Note:
> `<xx>` is the same ip except for the part where the number is, removed
> for security. When it changes to yy or zz they are different numbers.

=======================

## sftp

from server1:

```
# sftp -oPort=22 root@<server2.ip>
```

It just hanged, but eventually timed out:

```
ssh: connect to host <server2.ip> port 22: Connection timed out
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

from server2:

```
# sftp -oPort=22 root@<server1.ip>

ssh: connect to host <server1.ip> port 22: No route to host
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

closes connection, didn't take long to give above error and cut out.

======================

In traceroute at first, it failed in both directions.

I checked `/etc/ips` to check the IPs on the server.

I noticed the subnet mask didn't look right, it says 255.255.240.0. Then I looked up a subnet mask calculator, and noticed in the dropdown that the subnet mask of 255.255.240.0 goes to a /20 subnet.

Then I remembered seeing /20 in the output above, 255.255.240.0, which applies to a /20 subnet, instead of the proper subnet which should be a /28 subnet, which is the netmask of 255.255.255.240. So the netmask was wrong.

I updated the subnet mask and the broadcast in `/etc/ips` on server2 to the correct details, and also updated `eno1` which is the network file by adding the ip, and restarted the network.

Then I ran traceroute again, and got this from server2:

```
 # traceroute -T -p 22 <server1.ip>

 traceroute to <server1.ip> (<server1.ip>), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  gateway (server1.gateway.ip)  0.144 ms  0.159 ms  0.162 ms
 2   
 3  <part.of.hostname>.<city>.us.zip.zayo.com (<random.ip>)  0.946 ms  0.975 ms  0.962 ms
 4  * * <part.of.hostname2>.<city>..us.eth.zayo.com (<random.ip>)  0.896 ms
 5  * * *
 6  <part.of.hostname>.<FullCity>.Level3.net (<random.ip>)  4.022 ms  1.039 ms  1.060 ms
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  *^C
```

*(`^C` is just because I stopped it with control+C)*

From server1 I also tried the traceroute:

```
 # traceroute -T -p 22 <server2.ip>

traceroute to <hostname> (<server2.ip>), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  <some.other.ip> (<same.other.ip>)  0.268 ms  0.281 ms  0.283 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  *^C
```

That's what it did on both servers before I fixed the IP, but it's still not working to server2.

And `rsync` also still hangs from server2 to server1.

===============

## tcpdump

`tcpdump` from server1 while trying to connect ssh server2 ---> server1

```
# tcpdump -vv -i eno3 host server2.mydomain.com and port 22
listening on eno3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
^C
0 packets captured
15 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

`tcpdump` from server2 while trying to connect ssh server1 ---> server2

```
# tcpdump -vv -i eno1 host server1.mydomain.com and port 22
listening on eno1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
^C
0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

*(`^C` is where I pressed control+C to terminate it after maybe 10 seconds each)*

============================

## ss

from server1:

```
# ss -lt

State       Recv-Q Send-Q            Local Address:Port                             Peer Address:Port
LISTEN      0      45                            *:lrp                                         *:*
LISTEN      0      50                            *:submission                                  *:*
LISTEN      0      45                            *:prp                                         *:*
LISTEN      0      128                           *:pop3                                        *:*
LISTEN      0      45                            *:nbx-ser                                     *:*
LISTEN      0      128                           *:imap                                        *:*
LISTEN      0      128                           *:sunrpc                                      *:*
LISTEN      0      128                           *:webcache                                    *:*
LISTEN      0      45                            *:nbx-dir                                     *:*
LISTEN      0      50                            *:urd                                         *:*
LISTEN      0      128                   127.0.0.1:27217                                       *:*
LISTEN      0      10                      <nn>.14:domain                                      *:*
LISTEN      0      10                      <nn>.13:domain                                      *:*
LISTEN      0      10                      <nn>.12:domain                                      *:*
LISTEN      0      10                      <nn>.11:domain                                      *:*
LISTEN      0      10                      <nn>.10:domain                                      *:*
LISTEN      0      10                       <nn>.9:domain                                      *:*
LISTEN      0      10                       <nn>.8:domain                                      *:*
LISTEN      0      10                       <nn>.7:domain                                      *:*
LISTEN      0      10                       <nn>.6:domain                                      *:*
LISTEN      0      10                       <nn>.5:domain                                      *:*
LISTEN      0      10                       <nn>.4:domain                                      *:*
LISTEN      0      10                       <nn>.3:domain                                      *:*
LISTEN      0      10                       <nn>.2:domain                                      *:*
LISTEN      0      10                    127.0.0.1:domain                                      *:*
LISTEN      0      9                             *:ftp                                         *:*
LISTEN      0      50                            *:smtp                                        *:*
LISTEN      0      128                   127.0.0.1:rndc                                        *:*
LISTEN      0      128                           *:pcsync-https                                *:*
LISTEN      0      45                            *:tsrmagt                                     *:*
LISTEN      0      45                            *:tpcsrvr                                     *:*
LISTEN      0      45                            *:idware-router                               *:*
LISTEN      0      45                            *:autodesk-nlm                                *:*
LISTEN      0      128                           *:imaps                                       *:*
LISTEN      0      45                            *:infowave                                    *:*
LISTEN      0      128                           *:22                                          *:*
LISTEN      0      45                            *:radsec                                      *:*
LISTEN      0      128                           *:pop3s                                       *:*
LISTEN      0      45                            *:gnunet                                      *:*
LISTEN      0      45                            *:eli                                         *:*
LISTEN      0      80                         [::]:mysql                                    [::]:*
LISTEN      0      50                         [::]:submission                               [::]:*
LISTEN      0      128                        [::]:pop3                                     [::]:*
LISTEN      0      128                        [::]:imap                                     [::]:*
LISTEN      0      128                        [::]:sunrpc                                   [::]:*
LISTEN      0      128                        [::]:webcache                                 [::]:*
LISTEN      0      128                        [::]:http                                     [::]:*
LISTEN      0      50                         [::]:urd                                      [::]:*
LISTEN      0      9                          [::]:ftp                                      [::]:*
LISTEN      0      50                         [::]:smtp                                     [::]:*
LISTEN      0      128                        [::]:pcsync-https                             [::]:*
LISTEN      0      128                        [::]:https                                    [::]:*
LISTEN      0      128                        [::]:imaps                                    [::]:*
LISTEN      0      128                        [::]:22                                       [::]:*
LISTEN      0      128                        [::]:pop3s                                    [::]:*
```

> Note:
>
> ```
> <nn> is the first part of the IPs, removed for security
> ```

from server2:

```
# ss -lt

State      Recv-Q Send-Q     Local Address:Port                      Peer Address:Port
LISTEN     0      50                     *:submission                           *:*
LISTEN     0      45                     *:prp                                  *:*
LISTEN     0      128                    *:pop3                                 *:*
LISTEN     0      128            127.0.0.1:783                                  *:*
LISTEN     0      45                     *:nbx-ser                              *:*
LISTEN     0      128                    *:imap                                 *:*
LISTEN     0      128                    *:sunrpc                               *:*
LISTEN     0      128                    *:http                                 *:*
LISTEN     0      45                     *:nbx-dir                              *:*
LISTEN     0      50                     *:urd                                  *:*
LISTEN     0      128                    *:domain                               *:*
LISTEN     0      128                    *:ssh                                  *:*
LISTEN     0      50                     *:smtp                                 *:*
LISTEN     0      10             127.0.0.1:rndc                                 *:*
LISTEN     0      128                    *:https                                *:*
LISTEN     0      45                     *:tsrmagt                              *:*
LISTEN     0      45                     *:tpcsrvr                              *:*
LISTEN     0      45                     *:idware-router                        *:*
LISTEN     0      45                     *:autodesk-nlm                         *:*
LISTEN     0      128                    *:imaps                                *:*
LISTEN     0      45                     *:infowave                             *:*
LISTEN     0      45                     *:radsec                               *:*
LISTEN     0      128                    *:pop3s                                *:*
LISTEN     0      45                     *:gnunet                               *:*
LISTEN     0      45                     *:eli                                  *:*
LISTEN     0      80                  [::]:mysql                             [::]:*
LISTEN     0      50                  [::]:submission                        [::]:*
LISTEN     0      128                 [::]:pop3                              [::]:*
LISTEN     0      128                [::1]:783                               [::]:*
LISTEN     0      128                 [::]:imap                              [::]:*
LISTEN     0      128                 [::]:sunrpc                            [::]:*
LISTEN     0      128                 [::]:http                              [::]:*
LISTEN     0      50                  [::]:urd                               [::]:*
LISTEN     0      128                 [::]:domain                            [::]:*
LISTEN     0      128                 [::]:ssh                               [::]:*
LISTEN     0      50                  [::]:smtp                              [::]:*
LISTEN     0      128                 [::]:https                             [::]:*
LISTEN     0      128                 [::]:imaps                             [::]:*
LISTEN     0      128                 [::]:pop3s                             [::]:*
```

I noticed there are none of the server IPs in this list for server2. I'm not sure if there's supposed to be, but all the server IPs are in the list for server1.

## ping

- Attempts to `ping` the other server hostname from both directions
  hangs.
- Attempts to `ping` even a LIVE DOMAIN on the other server hangs! But
  the live domain is accessible through the internet! I can't
  `ping` any domains on either server from the other server that are working fine on the internet!
- `ping google.com` pings fine from both servers.
- `ping <server1.mydomain.com>` works from from CMD on my windows computer.
- `ping <server2.mydomain.com>` works from from CMD on my windows computer.

So both sites can be pinged, just not from between the two servers. In fact NOTHING on either server can be pinged from the other server.

I checked a millionth time and CSF is not blocking it. Same occurs even if CSF is completely disabled on both servers. I just completely disabled CSF on both servers and then tried to ping the other server or even a live domain on the other server from both directions, and it just hangs.

What could be blocking it?

Now I've resorted to checking to see if the the other server's IP exists anywhere on the other server.

From server1

```
# grep -rl "<server2.ip>" "/etc/"
/etc/hosts.allow
/etc/imunify360/whitelist/ext.txt
/etc/csf/csf.allow
```

From server2

```
# grep -rl "<server1.ip>" "/etc/"
/etc/hosts.allow
/etc/csf/csf.allow
```

No results from `/var/` on either server as expected. I'm just trying anything at this point.

===================

## iptables -nL

I disabled CSF on both servers and then ran `iptables -nL`, as well as another attempt to ping the other server from both directions.

**From server1:**

```
# iptables -nL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

server1 to server2 ping attempt with both server firewalls down:

```
# ping server2.mydomain.com
PING server2.mydomain.com (<server2.ip>) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- server2.mydomain.com ping statistics ---
31 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 29995ms
```

**From server2:**

```
# iptables -nL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

server2 to server1 ping attempt with both server firewalls down:

```
# ping server1.mydomain.com
PING server1.mydomain.com (<server1.ip>) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- server1.mydomain.com ping statistics ---
34 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 32999ms
```

=====================

Update: A couple more things to add. I got some output this time! Not sure if it helps

#### tcpdump

Started this from server1 and after running the `tcpdump` on server1, I went over to server2 tried to `ssh` to server1 from server2.

I captured something!! ssh still just hung and didn't connect, but maybe this will help.

*** server1 output ***

```
    # tcpdump -vv -i eno3 host server2.mydomain.com and port 22
    tcpdump: listening on eno3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
    11:26:14.056746 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 53597, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
        <server2.ip>.58458 > <server1.ip>.ssh: Flags [S], cksum 0x4391 (correct), seq 3670869813, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 298702440 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    11:26:14.056773 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 53250, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
        <server1.ip>.ssh > <server2.ip>.58458: Flags [R.], cksum 0x05a7 (correct), seq 0, ack 3670869814, win 0, length 0
    11:26:15.058440 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 53598, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
        <server2.ip>.58458 > <server1.ip>.ssh: Flags [S], cksum 0x3fa7 (correct), seq 3670869813, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 298703442 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    11:26:15.058470 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 53688, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    <...>
    ^C
    6 packets captured
    6 packets received by filter
    0 packets dropped by kernel
```

#### iperf

*** also server1 output ***

```
    # iperf -s
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    Server listening on TCP port 5001
    TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
    ------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136835/discussion-on-question-by-user7211-remote-ssh-connection-from-one-server-to-anot).

Comment: Whoever can help please continue to comment

Comment: The conversation can continue in the linked chat room, not in the comments. We try to avoid having long discussions in the comments and instead prefer to edit the question to include anything important that is added in comments. You have already done this (thank you!), so the comments weren't needed anymore. I would urge you to add a short summary of the issue though since this is getting quite long and not everyone will read through it.

Comment: You can repeat the -v option for more verbose logging, so “ssh -vvv …” to perhaps see more details instead of immediate hangs.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments before they were moved, I did try that but it still just hangs.

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question. I know our rules seem weird to new users (they seemed weird to me too!), but comments are hard to read easy to miss, support minimal formatting and are designed only for temporary clarifications. So anything useful that comes up in a comment really should be added to the question so the next person can see it.

Comment: Level 2 technical support staff also looked into it and verified there's no configuration error they can find on server2.

Comment: I never solved this. I had to work around the issue the long way, took literally days to transfer the data, and a lot of it I couldn't transfer.

Comment: rsync sucks. Plain and simple.